# Quadratic term has positive coefficient in simple regression, and negative in multiple regression?

Tags: regression, regression-coefficients

Is it normal, that quadratic term has positive coefficient in simple regression, and negative in multiple regression? 
Linear term of the same variable is positive in both cases...

Comment: maybe not normal (if you mean by normal "happens all the time"), but can sure happen

Comment: This is a particular example of a [well-known phenomenon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson%27s_paradox) (see the picture, in particular). It has a variety of names under different situations, but the short outcome is, if you omit an important explanatory variable, your esitmates may be severely biased (including sign changes).

Answer (score 4):

Yes, for instance, an increasing trend with a decreasing rate of increase will fit your description:

```
set.seed(127)
x <- rnorm(300, 10, 2)
y <- 10*x - .3*x^2 + rnorm(300, 0, 2)

plot(x,y)
```

[image]

```
> lm(y ~ I(x^2))

Coefficients:
(Intercept)       I(x^2)  
    48.6200       0.1938  

> lm(y ~ x)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)            x  
      28.09         4.07  

> lm(y ~ x + I(x^2))

Coefficients:
(Intercept)            x       I(x^2)  
    -1.9046      10.3900      -0.3195
```